# React cant use useParams values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, jsx

So my code was working with no issues until i added useParams

```
[...]

const promiseDelay = () => {
    const E_COMMERCE_API = "https://mocki.io/v1/027ebfda-9bd8-4b53-ae33-ab41586d773a";
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(fetch(E_COMMERCE_API)), 1000);
    });
};

export default function ItemDetailContainer() {
    const { itemId } = useParams();
    const [dataToShow, setDataToShow] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        promiseDelay()
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                const aux = data.find((element) => {
                    console.log(itemId); //<--- 2
                    // return element.id === itemId; <--- if i uncomment, i get no data
                    return element.id === 2; // with this line, everything works just fine
                });
                setDataToShow(aux);
            });
    }, []);

    [...]
}
```

Apparently even if itemId its 2 its not the same and wrecks everything.

Comment: Can you show the `<Route>` part of the parent component?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the string version of 2, which `2 === "2"` will cause a false as they are not the same type

Comment: @ChrisG <Route path="/ItemDetailContainer/:itemId" component={ItemDetailContainer} />

Comment: @PatrickEvans this fixed it lol, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the param is a string when it's parsed from the URL. The `useParams` hook doesn't know to parse it to a number.

So `element.id === Number(itemId)` should fix it.